# Is it possible to call a member function that moves the object?

Tags: c++, c++14, move, swap

Suppose I have a class `Foo` which has a member variable of type `std::vector<Bar>`:

```
class Foo;

class Bar
{
public:
    int x;
    Foo* parent;
    void trigger(size_t i);
};


class Foo
{
public:
    std::vector<Bar> arr;
    void moveBack(size_t i);
};

void Bar::trigger(size_t i)
{
    parent->moveBack(i);
}

void Foo::moveBack(size_t i)
{
    std::swap(arr[i], arr[arr.size()-1]);
}

int main()
{
    //...Init foo of type Foo and fill the arr
    foo.arr[3].trigger(3);
}
```

I am wondering if the code above is dangerous or undefined behaviour. Essentially the object of type `Bar` is moving itself.

Edit: Added forward declaration

Comment: It looks okay. The only "dangerous" part could be no bounds checking.

Comment: The other slightly nasty bit is that Bar knows that it's in an ordered list of some type ... which can become a headache when maintaining code; but that's in the realms of code review

Comment: please provide a [mcve]. You need at least a forward declaration to make this compile, actually I dont see how this coudl be fixed....

Comment: @tobi303 bar just contains a pointer to foo; so foward declare foo 1st, then bar, then foo.

Comment: There's no magic in moving. It doesn't turn the moved-from object into intergalactic gas or anything.